# How to solve TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, notion-api

I am a beginner who wants to build a blog using Notion API, Next.js and Tailwind CSS. I learned the following code from here: https://egghead.io/lessons/next-js-request-notion-database-data-from-the-api-with-next-js.

The following code works fine in `/post/index.js`, but I get this error when I put the following code into `/components/PostTest.js` and import it in `/index.js`.

How do I solve this problem?

#### Error information

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6IGs.png)

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

#line 9
return posts.map((posts) => (
```

#### Source Code

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import { Client } from "@notionhq/client";
import { useState } from "react";

export const PostPage = ({ posts }) => {
  const [post] = useState(null);

  return posts.map((posts) => (
    <div className="bg-[#F5F5F7] dark:bg-black px-4 py-2 md:py-4">
      <div className="bg-[#FFFFFF] dark:bg-[#141414] max-w-sm rounded-xl overflow-hidden shadow-sm container mx-auto">
        <img
          className="aspect-[16/9] bg-cover bg-center"
          src={posts.coverImage}
          alt="Post Banner"
        />
        <div className="px-6 py-4">
          <p className="text-[12px] md:text-[14px] dark:text-[#888888] leading-5 font-[700] pt-2 uppercase tracking-normal mb-[8px]">
            {posts.Category}
          </p>
          <Link href={`/post/${posts.PID}`}>
            <div className="text-lg md:text-xl text-[#1d1d1f] dark:text-[#F5F5F7] leading-snug font-[700]">
                {posts.Title}
            </div>
          </Link>
          <p className="text-[14px] text-[#6e6e73] dark:text-[#888888] leading-5 font-[600] pt-2">
            {new Date(posts.Date).toLocaleDateString()}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ));
};

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const notion = new Client({
    auth: process.env.NOTION_TOKEN,
  });

  // get posts more than 100 pages.
  let results = [];

  let data = await notion.databases.query({
    database_id: process.env.NOTION_POST_DATABASE_ID,
    filter: {
      property: "Status",
      select: {
        equals: "Published",
      },
    },
    sorts: [
      {
        property: "Date",
        direction: "descending",
      },
    ],
  });

  results = [...data.results];

  while (data.has_more) {
    data = await notion.databases.query({
      database_id: process.env.NOTION_POST_DATABASE_ID,
      filter: {
        property: "Status",
        select: {
          equals: "Published",
        },
      },
      start_cursor: data.next_cursor,
    });

    results = [...results, ...data.results];
  }

  const posts = results.map((post) => ({
    id: post.id,
    Title: post.properties.Title.title[0].text.content,
    Category: post.properties.Category.select.name,
    category_color: post.properties.Category.select.color,
    Date: post.properties.Date.date.start,
    Tags: post.properties.Tags.multi_select.map((Tags) => Tags.name),
    Tags_color: post.properties.Tags.multi_select.map((TagsColor) => TagsColor.color),
    PID: post.properties.PID.rich_text[0].text.content,
    Author: post.properties.Author.people.map((people) => people.name),
    Author_avatar_url: post.properties.Author.people.map((people) => people.avatar_url),
    coverImage:
        post.cover.file?.url ||
        post.cover.external?.url,
  }));

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
};

export default PostPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

if posts is null or it's not an array, you'll get that error.
Try this fix

```js
return (
    posts?.map((posts) => ( 
        ...
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `post` should be inited with an empty array:

```
  const [post, ] = useState([]);
```

Secondly, you cannot return an array of JSX, so wrap it in a Fragment or `<>`.

```
return (
  <>
      posts.map((posts) => ( 
        ...
      )
  </>
)
```